# cookies on localhost and hosting

Tags: ssl, cookies

My code is running smoothly on localhost. But it doesn't work on the web server; cookies are not saved.

```
if (isset($_POST['user-login-form'])) { 
    $user_mail = strip_tags(trim($_POST['l_email']));
    $user_password = strip_tags(sha1(md5($_POST['l_password'])));
    $usercontrol=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where user_mail=:user_mail and user_password=:user_password");
    $usercontrol->execute(array( 'user_mail' => $user_mail, 'user_password' => $user_password ));
    $userresult=$usercontrol->rowCount();
    if ($userresult==1) {
        $_SESSION['user_mail']=$user_mail;
        $_SESSION['user_password']=$user_password;
        if(isset($_POST['checkremember'])){
            setcookie("user_remember",$user_mail,strtotime("+10 week"));
        } else {
            setcookie("user_remember",$user_mail,strtotime("-10 week"));
        }
        echo "2";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "1";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Previously it worked without problems. I installed an SSL certificate and made several changes to the `.htaccess` file.

But when you type this on a blank page, the cookie is registered.
Code:

```
setcookie("user_remember", "deneme", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
echo $_COOKIE["user_remember"];
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved.
the problem is that the php file is utf-8 BOM.